# detect changes in a JS Object using Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I have a javascript object suppose `user` is the name of my object and in angular js it looks like this

```
$scope.user = {
  name:'Arpit',
  class:'Computer Science',
  year:'2017',
  gender:'male'
}
```

This object I am fetching from the database and opening in the edit screen, now if in the HTML form if any field got changed by the user in edit mode I want to highlight the particular field using my CSS class `applyborder`. My logic is working for the first time when I am changing any field value but when I reset the value as original the class should be removed, but it is not removing the class. My angular js code is:

```
            //Value Change Detection
            Object.keys($scope.user).filter(function (key) {
                $scope.$watch('user.' + key, function (newVal, oldVal) {
                    if (newVal != oldVal) {
                        var ele = $('[ng-model="user' + '.' + key + '"]');
                        ele.addClass("applyborder");
                    }
                    else  if(oldVal == newVal){
                        var ele = $('[ng-model="user' + '.' + key + '"]');
                        ele.removeClass("applyborder");
                    }
                });
            });
```

It is treating last entered value as `oldVal` but it should treat to the value which comes from the database. Thanks.

Comment: `else  if(oldVal == newVal){` is the two spaces a typo?

Comment: @Sravan is that relevant?

Comment: Don't know, just thought to correct the syntax. so I just asked a question so that he may correct it if it was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of `$watch`.

You can keep a copy of the object you received from database using `angular.copy`:

`var originalUser = angular.copy($scope.user)`.

then check:

```
//Value Change Detection
        Object.keys($scope.user).filter(function (key) {
            $scope.$watch('user.' + key, function (newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal != originalUser[key]) {
                    var ele = $('[ng-model="user' + '.' + key + '"]');
                    ele.addClass("applyborder");
                }
                else  if(originalUser[key] == newVal){
                    var ele = $('[ng-model="user' + '.' + key + '"]');
                    ele.removeClass("applyborder");
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: This is working fine but I have some date fields it is not working for date fields. should we need to add some `new Date()` somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Just apply it under `ng-dirty` class will do. You might have to isolate your css scope so it doesn't get applied everywhere.

```
<form class='myForm'>
  <input ng-model='xx' />
</form>

.myForm .ng-dirty {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

If you need to reset the state, you'll need to give the form a name.

```
<form class='myForm' name='myForm'>

$scope.myForm.$setPristine();
```